# GraphAware Dutch support for neo4j 3.5

Tags: neo4j, graphaware

What would be the options for us if we'd like to apply the annotation and keyword extraction, created by GraphAware, for the Dutch language in neo4j 3.5.

We are currently building a knowledge graph in Neo4j 3.5 for a bunch of textual articles. We'd like to leverage the plugins written in GraphAware in order to annotate text, extract keywords, etc. This all has great support for the English language, in particular with Stanford CoreNLP. However, Stanford CoreNLP doesn't support Dutch.

Therefore we are wondering what our options are to still leverage GraphAware functionalities, but also apply it on the Dutch language.

Thank you for your help.